# How to support jQuery Ajax Cross domain request with IE7

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-domain

I need to make some jQuery code compatible with IE7. However, I am making cross domain request. As of now, is there any easy, simple way to do cross domain request with IE7 using jQuery ajax ?

Comment: Please write what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

You can... IF you can control how the server sends the response...

Just use dataType='jsonp' in your .ajax() call.
jQuery will append a 'callback' parameter to the request and generate a random value for it.
On the server side you should wrap the response inside a function call.
The name of that function should be the value of the 'callback' parameter.

e.g. 
ajaxCall -> www.theserver.com?callback=whatever

(get the value of the callback parameter on the server)

server response -> whatever({actual json response});

You can get the value in the .done function of your .ajax call

Comment: Unfortunately i can't control that. I solve the problem by not solving it. In my organization we have Internet explorer 11. But the IT team has put a default of compatibility mode on our IE. So i have just added the metadata tag that tell IE to work in Mode 10. Problem solved